# Change color of PNG using CSS only

Tags: css

I have a PNG image containing a white logotype. Is it possible to change the color of the logotype from white to red using CSS only?

Comment: No. No. No. (and no)

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1:

You can convert the .png to .svg and change the color by code.

Solution 2:

A png with your logo in the middle, transparent, over a container, and changing the container's background color.

Comment: How? Unless the png is a Fireworks native file it will be a rasterised bitmap. To convert a bitmap to a vector (SVG) you have to redraw it. So basically your solution is "redraw it as an SVG"?

Comment: Ilustrator - image trace. If the logo isn't too difficult, the result should be perfect!

Answer (score 0):

[CSS filters](http://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/), once they have [more browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters), will be able to change display of images in some ways, but the best shot for changing the color that I see in very brief scrolling through [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) would be `hue-rotate`, and I'm not convinced that could turn white into non-white.

Answer (score -1):

This is how you do it with [`CSS filters`](https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/)

```css
    .white2red {
        filter: sepia(100%) saturate(100);
    }
```